# Pyes search on particular field gives no results

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I have a document indexed whose structure is as follows:

```
{
  "_index": "yelp",
  "_type": "user",
  "_id": "ABC",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "yelping_since": "2007-07",
    "votes": {},
    "review_count": 1798,
    "name": "TEST_USER",
    "user_id": "123",
    "friends": [],
    "fans": 89,
    "average_stars": 3.48,
    "type": "user",
    "compliments": {},
    "elite": []
  }
}
```

When I do:

```
myFilter = TermFilter("_id", "ABC")
q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(), myFilter).search()
results = conn.search(query=q, indices=index_name,type=doc_typeU)
```

Exact result is displayed.

But when I try to search for field say user_id as follows,

```
myFilter = TermFilter("user_id", "123")
q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(), myFilter).search()
results = conn.search(query=q, indices=index_name,type=doc_typeU)
```

No results are displayed. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the mapping of that index?

Comment: I think I have used default index. I haven't done or created any mapping during indexing the documents.

Comment: Then it should work. Haven't tested this with Pyes but in plain ES with REST calls it works as expected.

Comment: I even tried with normal ES with doing a POST/_search. The below works {
   "fields" : ["name", "user_id"],
   "query" : {
        "term" : { "_id" : "ABC" }
    }
} But this doesn't work {
   "fields" : ["name", "user_id"],
   "query" : {
        "term" : { "user_id" : "123" }
    }
} Any idea how to debug or to fetch documents based on field search. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Execute this `GET /yelp/user/_mapping` and update the question with the result.

Comment: {
  "yelp": {
    "mappings": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "average_stars": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "fields": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "query": {
            "properties": {
              "match_all": {
                "type": "object"
              },
              "term": {
                "properties": {
                  "user_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }

Comment: ,
          "term": {
            "properties": {
              "user": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "user_id": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "user_id": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} Divided the mapping in two comments as it was too long. Also I have removed mapping of some fields sue to space issue. Thanks.

Comment: There is kind of a mess in there. You used POST/_search, that's not right. It should be used with GET. Also, you have in the mapping a field called "query" and another one called "term". I suspect this is because you used POST/_search. I suggest starting over with your mapping (delete the index, create it again, add data and test).

Comment: try this >>>
TermFilter("_user_id", "123")
_ (undescore infornt of user_id)

Answer (score 0):

### please try this one

```
myFilter = TermQuery("user_id", "123")
q = FilteredQuery(MatchAllQuery(), myFilter).search()
results = conn.search(query=q, indices=index_name,type=doc_typeU)
```